# jQuery '.each' and attaching '.click' event

Tags: jquery, each

I am not a programer but I enjoy building prototypes. All of my experience comes from actionScript2.

Here is my question. To simplify my code I would like to figure out how to attach '.click' events to div's that are already existing in the HTML body.

```
<body>
<div id="dog-selected">dog</div>
<div id="cat-selected">cat</div>
<div id="mouse-selected">mouse</div>

<div class="dog"><img></div>
<div class="cat"><img></div>
<div class="mouse"><img></div>
</body>
```

My (failed) strategy was:
1) make an array of objects:

```
var props = {
"dog": "false",
"cat": "true",
"mouse": "false"
};
```

2) iterate through the array with '.each' and augment each existing div with a '.click' event. Lastly, construct a local variable.

here is a prototype:

```
$.each(props, function(key, value) {    
$('#'+key+'-selected').click(function(){
var key = value;  
});
});
```

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Jwqfg/) what you are looking for ?

Comment: That appears to work, what's the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/PV7Gj/

Comment: Your code already does everything it's coded to do. did you actually want to do something with the key variable inside the click event?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

One solution you could use is to assign a more generalized class to any div you want the click event handler bound to.

For example:

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="dog" class="selected" data-selected="false">dog</div>
<div id="cat" class="selected" data-selected="true">cat</div>
<div id="mouse" class="selected" data-selected="false">mouse</div>

<div class="dog"><img/></div>
<div class="cat"><img/></div>
<div class="mouse"><img/></div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$( ".selected" ).each(function(index) {
    $(this).on("click", function(){
        // For the boolean value
        var boolKey = $(this).data('selected');
        // For the mammal value
        var mammalKey = $(this).attr('id'); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Interesting can you include variables in div's? is that valid HTML?

Thanks for all of the input folks! In the act of writing this prototype and post I seem to have worked out the problem. Indeed it does wort just fine! but thank you all for your contributions!

Comment: These are not so much variables, as attributes.  The id and class are pretty standard, but you can append data-{name} to elements and access the content with $(this).data('{name}');  This is valid html5.

Answer (score 28):

No need to use `.each`. `click` already binds to all `div` occurrences.

```
$('div').click(function(e) {
    ..    
});
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7semfsrj/)

Note: use hard binding such as `.click` to make sure dynamically loaded elements don't get bound.

Comment: Yes but that won't work on archives when you have a button on each entry.

Comment: @Oriol is right, the other way is to use `on()` jQuery function. This way it will work with dynamic loaded content.

Comment: This explanation helped immensely, thank you.